# CSS Changes Not Reflecting Immediately on cPanel VPS with or without Cloudflare: Suspected Cache Issue

Tags: css, cpanel, cloudflare, web-hosting, vps

1. I have a VPS, and I've installed cPanel. The developers are attempting to upload fresh CSS files, and it's working; the changes are reflected quickly.
2. However, when our developers try to change and re-upload the files, the upload is successful, but the changes take 2-3 hours to be reflected. It continues to show the old files. I suspect a cache issue.
3. I am facing this issue both when using CDN (Cloudflare) for my domain and when not using CDN. The problem is consistent for both domains.
4. I am not using any specific cache rules in my Cloudflare settings.
5. I am facing the same issue for all the domains I use in cPanel, whether or not I am using CDN for the domain.

**What I have tried:**

- Checked for immediate reflection of changes when uploading fresh CSS files, which works as expected.
- Observed a delay of 2-3 hours in changes reflecting after re-uploading the CSS files.
- Verified that the issue persists both with and without using CDN (Cloudflare) for the domain.
- Confirmed that the problem is consistent across all domains hosted on cPanel, regardless of CDN usage.
- Ensured no specific cache rules are configured in Cloudflare settings.
- Considered the possibility of a cache issue but seeking guidance on potential solutions.

**What I was expecting:**

- Immediate reflection of changes after re-uploading CSS files, similar to the quick updates observed with the initial file upload.
- Understanding and resolution of the delay issue, especially when changes are made and re-uploaded by developers.
- Insights into potential cache-related problems and recommendations on how to address them.
- Suggestions on troubleshooting steps to identify the root cause of the delay.
- Guidance on whether there are specific configurations within cPanel or Cloudflare that might impact the update speed.

Comment: Try to add this string at the end of css files ?ver=1 so your css will look like main.css?ver=1